# sparql query returns HTTPException

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web

I am running the following query on Jena in eclipse:

```
public static ArrayList<String> testing(){
    String parql;
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    parql="PREFIX yago:<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/>"+
            "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-synta-ns#>"+
            "SELECT ?entity where {?entity rdf:type yago:wordnet_writer_110794014}";
    Query query2 = QueryFactory.create(parql);
    QueryExecution qexec2 = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql", query2);
    ResultSet results2 = qexec2.execSelect();
    while(results2.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution result = results2.nextSolution();
        String allindivs = result.get("entity").toString();
        list2.add(allindivs);
    }

        return list2;
}
```

All I get is

> Exception in thread "main" HttpException: 500

The same query works fine on the endpoint. Is this issue temporary? Because I believe the same code worked fine previously. I assume there is something wrong with the Yago server.

Comment: Have you tried visiting [http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql](http://lod2.openlinksw.com/sparql) in a web browser? I just did and got **"The web-site you are currently trying to access is under maintenance at this time. We are sorry for any inconvenience this has caused."**

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, yes Sir! I tried! I guess that indeed it is a server issue. This leads me to wonder about the possibility of storing the YAGO ontologies in a local base where I dont have to query over their endpoint

Comment: That;s certainly an option;  they're available for download, after all.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Could you make that the answer? It's still open now, even though the underlying issues have been resolved.

Comment: @Spork Actually, I think that this question falls under the category of "This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."  Since it's just a matter of being unavailable for a while (not at all uncommon), I think that OP should probably just delete the question.